# how to handle command line arguments with UI page in bootstrapper in WiX

Tags: wix, custom-action, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper setup which accepts command line parameters as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501995/pass-parameters-from-bootstrapper-to-msi-bundle-package) link and as mentioned below:

```
<Wix>
  <Bundle>
    <Variable Name="CommandLineArg" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArg" Value="[CommandLineArg]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

I use this command line argument to conditionally run a custom action. This works fine if I run this through command line, i.e. if I pass the parameter, the customaction runs and if not then it doesnt run. But what I want is when the user initiates it through UI, i.e., by double clicking the package, the user is shown the EULA page and if the user accepts it then all the custom actions should run including the one which has the condition based on the command line argument. How do I ensure that because right now what happens is that the customaction is not run when the installation is initiated from the command line.

Any suggestions are welcome. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value to your variable.

For example:

```
<Wix>
  <Bundle>
    <Variable Name="CommandLineArg" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="hello"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArg" Value="[CommandLineArg]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

This way CommandLineArg will always have a value even if the user double-clicks your installer.