# How to pass AddLocal-Parameter from wix standard bootstrapper to a MsiPackage

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11

With WIX Tools v3.10 I used to add a variable `AddLocal` to the bundle which I passed to the `MsiProperty` with the `Name="ADDLOCAL"` as described [by BryanJ in "Pass parameters from bootstrapper to msi bundle package"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10504382/6240645).

```
<Bundle>
...
  <Variable Name="InstallLevel" Type="numeric" bal:Overridable="yes" Value="1"/>
  <Variable Name="AddLocal" Type="string" bal:Overridable="yes" Value=""/>
  <Chain>
    <MsiPackage Id="Addin64bit_loc" Vital="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" ...
                EnableFeatureSelection="yes" >
      ...
      <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLEVEL" Value="[InstallLevel]"/>
      <MsiProperty Name="ADDLOCAL" Value="[AddLocal]"/>
    </MsiPackage>
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Now after switching to v3.11 I get this warning which will turn to an error in v4:

```
Warning CNDL1149: The 'ADDLOCAL' MsiProperty is controlled by the bootstrapper and cannot be authored. 
(Illegal properties are: 'ACTION', 'ADDLOCAL', 'ADDSOURCE', 'ADDDEFAULT', 'ADVERTISE', 'ALLUSERS', 'REBOOT', 'REINSTALL', 'REINSTALLMODE', or 'REMOVE'.) 
Remove the MsiProperty element. 
This restriction will be enforced as an error in WiX v4.0.
```

So what is the adequate way in v3.11 to pass an ADDLOCAL parameter from bootstrapper command line to the Msi?

Comment: The change in WIX behavior was introduced in commit https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/commit/defd78e8a7e37a3b9b36cfaf6dec2af68344d202, which was work to fix this bug: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5294.

Answer (score 1):

you can influence on ADDLOCAL parameter in your custom bootstrapper project something like that:

```
_bootstrapper.PlanMsiFeature += (_, ea) =>
{
    ea.State = (needToInstall) ? FeatureState.Local : FeatureState.Absent;
};
```

Comment: I don't have a custom bootstrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and ended up using a transform with only the ADDLOCAL property set.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using AddLocal, I found adding code like:

```
<Feature Id="FeatureB" Level="0">
  <Condition Level="1">INSTALL_FEATUREB="1" OR FEATUREB_INSTALLED="1" 
  </Condition>
</Feature>
```

to my msi file behaved in a reasonable manner, allowing me to add/remove a feature.
Modified from:
using https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912227-Control-feature-states-for-silent-install-

I like using the 'Variable=X' syntax because I find it easier to read. Without the FEATUREB_INSTALLED test I found uninstall did not act as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always pass a value to a Variable from the Code behind like this.

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["AddLocal"] = "your value";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure engine variables are not related to the msi properties