# Detect if an installation is made via .msi or .exe

Tags: c#, wix, outlook-addin, bootstrapper

I have an outlook plugin which can be installed via .msi or .exe. In my solution I have a project Wix (for msi) and one Bootstrapper (for exe).I need to find a way to figure out during the installation if it is .exe installation or if it is .msi installation. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Make the installers set a registry key/create a file?

Comment: As you said, .exe is just the bootstrapper for the same .msi. This bootstrapper runs the same MSI package. You make pass parameter into it via command like bootstrapper uses. after that you have your difference as of this parameter value.

Comment: Yes, if you are using WiX it's always an MSI underneath, so maybe it would be better to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, because you believe that knowing that MSI/EXE difference is a solution.

Comment: @PhilDW I need to track how many users install via msi and how many users install via exe. So I need to set a parameter which will say to me if the installation was made via .exe or .msi. I don't know how to figure out which installation was used.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov how can I pass through bootstrapper a parameter? Do you refer via the .wxs file?

Comment: Is this what are you asking? [Pass parameters from bootstrapper to msi bundle package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501995/pass-parameters-from-bootstrapper-to-msi-bundle-package)

Comment: yes, thank you very much. I resolved my problem :)